# How to get extended sRGB Colorspace in obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to alter the color value.
Need to transform between RGB --> HSV -->RGB and so on.

Unfortunately -getHue() method didnt work with normal sRGB.

```
[col getHue:&hue saturation:&sat brightness:&val alpha:&alpha];

    NSLog(@"HUE == %f", hue);
    NSLog(@"SAT == %f", sat);
    NSLog(@"VAL == %f", val);
```

My application require to support iOS9 +. I have no idea how to change colorspace to extendedSRGB with old obj-c API .

> On versions of iOS before iOS 10, and for apps linked on a version of
>   iOS prior to iOS 10, colors are created and returned in one of two
>   color spaces:
>
> ```
> Device-Dependent Gray
>
> Device-Dependent RGB
> ```
>
> These device color spaces correspond closely to the display
>   characteristics of the sRGB color space. Color component values within
>   these color spaces are represented by values between 0.0 and 1.0. When
>   a color is created, the input parameters are clamped to fit within
>   this color space.
>
> If your app was linked on or after iOS 10 and when running on iOS 10
>   or later, colors are created in extended color spaces:
>
> ```
> kCGColorSpaceExtendedGray
>
> kCGColorSpaceExtendedSRGB
> ```

And thats it my whole project become frozen with this unsolved API problem.
:o  Can someone guide me how to change colorspace to extendedRGB (iOS9 API) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My application require to support iOS9 +. I have no idea how to change colorspace to extendedSRGB with old obj-c API .

The extended color spaces did not exist before iOS 10. As such it is not possible to use them on iOS 9 or earlier. See Apple’s documentation here where they list the versions that supported `kCGColorSpaceExtendedSRGB`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/kcgcolorspaceextendedsrgb

> SDKs
>
> - iOS 10.0+
> - macOS 10.12+
> - tvOS 10.0+
> - watchOS 3.0+